# Clear strings between strings

Tags: java

For example I have a string like this:

```
String myString = "Hello my name is Skypit"
```

How can I clear everything between "my" and "is"?
"my" and "is" will never change, but everything in between.
So the result for this example should be "Hello myis Skypit"

Comment: The question is not clear? "by everything in between my and is" are you referring to "name" or does that include "Hello" and "Skypit" too?

Comment: Question is not clear enough. Could you please explain it on example.

Comment: you want a result like this : `Hello myis Skypit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `(.*my).*(is.*)` with `replaceAll`

`(.*my)` : capture everything till `my` where `(.*my)` is represented by `$1`

`(is.*)` : capture everything from `is` to the end , where `(is.*)` is represented by `$2`

```
    String myString = "Hello my name is Skypit";
    System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("(.*my).*(is.*)", "$1$2"));

    // get the value in s
    // String s = myString.replaceAll("(.*my).*(is.*)", "$1$2");
```

output:

```
Hello myis Skypit
```

---

To fetch the content between `my` and `is`

```
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll(".*my(.*)is.*", "$1")); //
```

---

Demo

```js
const regex = /(.*my).*(is.*)/g;
const regex2 = /.*my(.*)is.*/g;
const str = `Hello my name is Skypit`;
const result = str.replace(regex, `$1$2`);
const result2 = str.replace(regex2, `$1`);
console.log('Output 1 : ',result);
console.log('Output 2 : ',result2);
```